# Silverlight iframe issue with google chrome - works in Firefox & IE

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome, iframe

I have an application, built in silverlight that I am calling via an iframe.

In IE, firefox the applications buttons work but in google chrome they do not..

I am pulling my hair out and am thinking that it is a bug in Google Chrome.

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

URL: http://gotek.dev.pixel-geeks.co.uk/

Click on the "Click here to try our panel live!" button to see the issue.

Comment: Did you managed to find the solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

It is a Chrome bug that Google has previously fixed but has risen again.

There are reports that it only affects if app running in windowless mode.